# Same file in differents tabs

Tags: sublime-text-2

in sublime with `ALT+SHIFT+2`, I get two columns for files.

in vim, with `split`, I can see the same file in differents parts of code.

in Sublime,for comparate differents parts of code,  How I can see the same file in two columns ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ALT+SHIFT+2` to open a new column

`File -> New View into File` to open a new tab with the same file

Then you can drag the second tab into the new column

Comment: Instead of drag the tabs it's possible to use `CTRL-ALT-2` to move the  newly opened file to the second column.